# Excluding elements with a prefix and all its children in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery("body *:not([id|='keep'])").removeAttr('id');
```

will target all elements on the page other than those whose prefix starts with `keep` and removes their id attribute.

Now I am trying to include not just the prefixed element but also its children in the exclusion list.

Something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
jQuery("body *:not([id|='keep']), body *:not([id|='keep']).find('*')").removeAttr('id');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `find()` is a method, not a selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter every element in the collection by whether it has an ancestor that matches `[id|='keep']`. You can also put `[id]` in the initial selector to only select elements that have an ID:

```
jQuery("body [id]:not([id|='keep'])")
  .filter(function() { return !this.closest('[id|="keep"]') })
  .removeAttr('id');
```

```js
jQuery("body [id]:not([id|='keep'])")
  .filter(function() { return !this.closest('[id|="keep"]') })
  .removeAttr('id');
  
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keep">
  <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
<div id="keep-2">keep-2</div>
<div id="somethingelse">somethingelse</div>
```